# Async script for Mongodb in node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I like to add some changes to my mongo database. But it is realy hard to do these changes in node.

I have a database with tree collections.

1. Places => _id, name, place_id
2. New_Places => _id, name, place_id
3. Tasks=>  _id, task, place_name,

The collection tasks has a column called: places
The place is directing to the name of the place in the collection places. Not the _id but the name

This is what I need to do. 
Compare the Places => place_id with "New_Places" => place_id and add the value of New_Places => name to the collection Places => new_name

The collection will be: Places => _id, name, place_id, new_name

Now I need to replace the Task => place_name with the Places=> new_name.

Then remove the Places collection and rename the New_Places to Places

The problem I face if that I need have a waterfall of async code to run this script. Is there a way to make those changes in one run?

Comment: Use Async Waterfall method https://github.com/caolan/async

Answer (score 0):

So, the Task => place_name needs to be Places => new_name, which needs to be New_Places => name which becomes Places after the last rename in your scenario.

I think you can achieve the same thing if you just update Places => name and Task => place_name with that new name.